# Searching for data in 3 tables but connected linearly?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables,

**Stud:**

sid(PK), lastname, firstname, title, dob, gender

This is a table full of student information,

**prog :**

pid(PK), ptitle, paward, length, did

This is a table full of university programs such as

pid = G500
ptitle = computer science..

and

**Enrl :**

sid, pid, lbl, status

What I need to get is information from `Stud` to `Enrl` to `Prog`.

Such as a student with the `SID`, I could natural join it to enrl to get all related fields and then match the `pid` from that newly created table to the `pid` of prog but for the life of me in SQL I cannot figure it out.

I've tried stuff such as

```
 select ptitle 
 from prog 
 where prog.pid in 
    (select * from stud, enrl where stud.sid = enrl.sid)
```

but this does not allow you to chose the `student` number to search for or even work in that case.

Anyone help a brother out here?

Comment: "then match the pid from that newly created table to the pid of prog" - you mean you want to join that table too? You can do multiple joins at once, e.g. `select * from stud, enrl, prog where stud.sid = enrl.sid and prog.pid = enrl.pid`. If you wanted to use `in ()` then you should just select the `enrl.pid` in the sub clause, not `*`.

Comment: so along the lines of "SELECT * FROM stud, enrl,prog WHERE stud.sid = enrl.sid and enrl.pid = prog.pid" @Rup

Comment: Hi. Did my answer work for you? Please it accept if so.

Answer (score 1):

I think these 2 examples should give you a start. Tweak them to fit your needs.

```
-- all programs for a single student
SELECT p.ptitle
FROM prog p
  INNER JOIN enrl e USING (pid)
WHERE
  e.sid = 1000

-- all students for a single program
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname
FROM stud s
  INNER JOIN enrl e USING (sid)
WHERE
  e.pid = 'G500'
```

if you need information from both `prog` and `stud` tables, you can use multiple joins in 1 query...

```
SELECT p.ptitle, s.firstname, s.lastname
FROM prog p
  INNER JOIN enrl e USING (pid)
  INNER JOIN stud s USING (sid)
```

references:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html
- http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/inner-vs-outer-joins/